# FFmpeg : How to replace video background color with transparency? (while capturing)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I want to capture a window and overlay it on another video.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i MainVideo.avi 
-f gdigrab -framerate 25 -video_size 300x200 -i title="MyWindow" 
-filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[b][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v]"
-map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -r 25  out.mp4
```

background of my window is black.

How can I replace this black color with transparency?

is this possible by ffmpeg? (I think it is possible by chromakey/colorkey filters but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to use those filters)

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Suppose this is a frame of video that I want:
[image]

Comment: GDIgrab supplies RGB feed so colorkey can work here, but if you share a sample frame of the grab, then I can see if a more effective alt method is possible.

Comment: @Mulvya, Hi , my question updated.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38578363/5726027). But insert `format=yuv444p` filter before the `geq` and instead of `16`, you may have to use a value of 0 or near 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDIgrab supplies a RGB feed so the colorkey filter can work here.

Try

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -video_size 300x200 -i title="MyWindow"
-filter_complex
"[1]split[m][a];
 [a]format=yuv444p,geq='if(gt(lum(X,Y),0),255,0)',hue=s=0[al];
 [m][al]alphamerge[ovr];
 [0][ovr]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v]"
-map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -r 25 out.mp4
```

You may have to use a value of near 0, if 0 doesn't capture all the transparent area.

Comment: Thank you so much! , it works for me with 16 instead of 0. ( `...(X,Y),16),255,0...` instead of `...(X,Y),0),255,0...`

Comment: @Gyan Can you share a command that only changes the background color to another color. My case doesn't have video scale, title, etc...

Comment: what mean `hue=s=0` work here, thanks

Comment: Set saturation to zero in hue filter.